# Excel : How do I call the "active cell" to a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have Excel 2013

Currently i have a code that takes any cell i click on and shows its contents to another cell as well.

My digging through the internet came up with the code below.

How do i call this to a cell with a custom formula instead of editing the code every time i want to change the location (b15) in this case?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
Range("B15").Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: i need to be able to tell a cell "=ActiveCell"  
 
This script for all intents and purposes says "B15=ActiveCell" ... so With what I have if click A1 and its contents are "The sunshine is good" B15 shows the same thing. If i then click C1 and it has "411" B15 shows that same thing.

Comment: Using a Custom Formula? What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to tell any cell to be like B15 by going to it and saying something like "=ActiveCell"

Comment: The `Target` in case of a single selection is the `ActiveCell`. To store the value of the active cell in another cell, you will have to explicitly specify like you did in the code above. Also you cannot change any other cell using Excel formula.

Comment: Even if you `Could` get the `ActiveCell`, the moment you select any other cell to enter the formula that will become the active cell and you will loose the previous selection.

Answer (score 2):

In a **standard module** include:

```
Public Function ShowMe() As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    ShowMe = ActiveCell.Value
End Function
```

and in the **worksheet code area** include:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: Either I'm failing to do something obvious or it isn't working... Here's what i did right clicked the sheet view code, pasted the second in sheet one, saved. Did - insert - module, pasted the first in. when i go to a cell and put =ShowMe it returns "#NAME?"  (keep in mind im not too familiar with these things.

Comment: The **#NAME?** means we must use **=ShowME()** rather than **=ShowMe**

Comment: Needs a little fixing - i can't copy paste stuff inside the sheet. If thats a long stretch you can try and mod the first formula to not return an error when i click on a hyperlink that sends me to another sheet and cell.